Debian "NO_PUBKEY C47F8A8AAD743EF7" for fasttrack
From the info at https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Debian_10_.22Buster.22.2C_Debian_11_.22Bullseye.22.2C_and_Debian_12_.22Bookworm.22-1
I ran:
sudo apt install lsb-release
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian $(lsb_release -cs)-backports main contrib" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list

echo "deb http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ $(lsb_release -cs)-fasttrack main contrib" |
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fasttrack.list
echo "deb http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack/ $(lsb_release -cs)-backports-staging main contrib" |
sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/fasttrack.list

However this is giving me an error when apt update:
chris@debiandev:~/projects$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease                          
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease                  
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports InRelease                
Get:5 http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-fasttrack InRelease [12.9 kB]
Get:6 http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-backports-staging InRelease [12.9 kB]
Err:5 http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-fasttrack InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C47F8A8AAD743EF7
Err:6 http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-backports-staging InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C47F8A8AAD743EF7
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-fasttrack InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C47F8A8AAD743EF7
E: The repository 'http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-fasttrack InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-backports-staging InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C47F8A8AAD743EF7
E: The repository 'http://fasttrack.debian.net/debian-fasttrack bookworm-backports-staging InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

I can't seem to find a google result with this exact public key vaule so I'm a bit concerned here to just blindly add this public with sudo apt-key adv .... Am I missing a step here
I'm using Debian 12 bookworm.

You skipped this part of the instructions, after adding the backports repository:
sudo apt install fasttrack-archive-keyring

That package is available in the main repositories, so you can install it before adding the fasttrack repositories.
